# Динамически растягивать слова на любую высоту экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

Есть такая маленькая программа, которая динамически меняет слово внутри SVG.
Необходимо добиться такого эффекта, чтобы независимо от слова или группы слов они всегда растягивались по всей высоте (так как их поввернули на 90 градусов), изменяя размер шрифта, но не меняя расстояние между буквами.

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let input = document.getElementById("input");

function changeWord() {
    text.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 12 75">
  <text id="text" transform="rotate(90 0 0)">Skibidi</text>
</svg>

<input value="Skibidi" oninput="changeWord()" id="input" type="text">
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Dynamically stretch words to any screen height](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62772980/7394871) от участника  [@Даниил Сазонов](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13883897/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d0%a1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62772980/7394871

Answer (score 5):

Вместо изменения размера шрифта вы можете изменить атрибут viewBox, чтобы высота viewBox совпадала с вычисленной длиной текста:

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
function changeWord() {
  text.innerHTML = input.value;
  svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-4 0 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  border:1px solid;
}

input {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-4 0 16 75">
  <g transform="rotate(90 0 0)">
  <text id="text">Skibpidi</text>
  </g>
</svg>

<input value="Skibidi" oninput="changeWord()" id="input" type="text">
```

Обратите внимание, что для того, чтобы освободить место для потомков (p) я изменил начальный
viewBox на `-4 0 16 75`

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Dynamically stretch words to any screen height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62773458/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>